# Calculate taylor series in Wolfram Mathematica or Maple

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, maple, mathematica

I want to calc the Taylor Series Expansion of $Â(z) = z\sum_{j\ge0}(e^z - e^{(1 - 2^{-j})z})$ at $z=0$, but I can't figure out a way to handle the infinite summation.

When I ask Maple

`taylor(z*(Sum(e^z - e^((1-2^(-j))*z), j = 0 .. infinite)), z = 0, 8)`

it gives me

$$\left(\sum_{j=0}^\inf\left(-(1-2^{-j})ln(e) +  ln(e)\right)\right)z^2 + \left(\sum_{j=0}^\inf\left(-\frac{1}{2}(1-2^{-j})^2ln(e)^2 +  \frac{1}{2}ln(e)^2\right)\right)z^3 + ...$$

which is not what I expected. Before someone ask, I didn't really know what to expect of this, but I was kinda hoping for values, not summations.  Is it possible to evaluate those infinite summations?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the taylor series expansion of some function around a some point consists of infinite series summations approximating the function around (i.e. "very close" to ..) the point at which the expansion is calculated. Such expansions are convergent close to the point of expansion. This is why we speak of a "radius of convergence" for such series expansions.

What you can do to compute the values of such series (and thus to approximate the value of the initial function) is the following: Choose a value of $z$ with "small" modulus (close to zero, i.e. inside the radius of convergence) and sum the first few terms of the series. Ignore the rest. The smaller the value of the modulus, the fewer the necessary terms of summation. You can experiment yourself, on how many terms of the series are needed in order for the sum to stabilize (depending on the accuracy you need).

Answer (score 1):

Without giving much thought to the math, in Maple you could try this crude approach:

```
orig := z*Sum(exp(z)-exp((1-2^(-j))*z),j=0..infinity):

solA := sort(value(combine(convert(taylor(orig,z=0,10),polynom)))):

lprint(solA);

  416107/3794874300*z^9+75133/89291160*z^8+197/35154*z^7
  +247/7812*z^6+46/315*z^5+11/21*z^4+4/3*z^3+2*z^2

solB := sort(expand(value(
               z*Sum(convert(taylor(exp(z)-exp((1-2^(-j))*z),z=0,10),
                             polynom),j=0..infinity)))):

lprint(solB);

  1175130769/93080676830400*z^10
  +416107/3794874300*z^9+75133/89291160*z^8+197/35154*z^7
  +247/7812*z^6+46/315*z^5+11/21*z^4+4/3*z^3+2*z^2

plot([solA-orig], z=-1.0 .. 1.0);
plot([solB-orig], z=-1.0 .. 1.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:

$$e^z - e^{(1-2^{-j})z} = e^z \left( 1 - e^{-2^{-j} z} \right) = -e^z \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-2^{-j})^k}{k!} z^k,$$ so we have $$\hat A(z) = - z e^z \sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-2^{-j})^k}{k!} z^k = -z e^z \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!} \sum_{j=0}^\infty ((-2)^k)^{-j} = -ze^z \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-2z)^k}{(2^k - 1)k!}.$$  Now we need to expand $e^z$ as a series and multiply the resulting two power series; this can be achieved in *Mathematica* as follows:

```
S[n_, z_] : = -z Series[Exp[z], {z, 0, n}] Sum[(-2 z)^k/((2^k - 1) k!), {k, 1, n+1}]
```

which will give output that is accurate to at least $O(z^{n})$ if I have done things correctly.  For example, `S[10, z]` gives the output

$$2 z^2+\frac{4 z^3}{3}+\frac{11 z^4}{21}+\frac{46 z^5}{315}+\frac{247 z^6}{7812}+\frac{197 z^7}{35154} \\ 
+\frac{75133 z^8}{89291160}+\frac{416107 z^9}{3794874300}+\frac{1175130769 z^{10}}{93080676830400} \\
+\frac{222224099 z^{11}}{170647907522400}+\frac{170006814269 z^{12}}{1397265066793411200}+O\left(z^{13}\right)$$

and we can evaluate this for specific $z$ by first using `Normal[]` to remove the $O(z^{13})$ term.

I should also point out that your Maple syntax could be causing a problem, because it does not appear that Maple recognizes `e^z` as $\exp(z)$, since your output has the term `ln(e)`.  You should instead specify the function as `exp(z)`; I suspect you will obtain results in agreement with mine.

Comment: and why would one expect that this summation will produce something deifferent than OP's original series?

Comment: @KonKan Because I am only making a disclaimer because I did not thoroughly check my work, and I did not formally investigate convergence.  All I did was quickly write down the first thing that came to my mind.  Others are more than welcome to flesh out the details.

Comment: What I meant, is that your result will coincide with OP's original series. However, I feel that the question seems to be not how we will derive the series expansion (OP seems to know how to do this) but on how this infinite series will be used for an actual computation.

Comment: @KonKan The *Mathematica* code gives a means to do both.  Actual computation follows directly from the explicit series expansion I have furnished, and in fact, is more tractable than the original form given by the OP.  Judging from the OP's Maple command, I do not agree with your assertion that the OP knows how to derive the series expansion.

Comment: ah ok. I have no knowledge of Mapple and I simply assumed that he/she did it right. If this is not so, then I agree.

Comment: Ok this is embarassing. Now that you have pointed out, ln(e) is 1 and doesn't need to be there. Thanks for your answer. I'll take sometime tonight to check on what you did and I'll come back later.